# Static Web App Deploy with Azure using specific Node version

Tags: node.js, azure, github-actions

I am trying to deploy a static web app using Azure services with Github Actions.

The problem is, I need to run a script using NodeJS. I am using ESM modules which are working fine in Node v14. The problem is, during build task Azure (or github) uses v12.8 (LTS I guess) where ESM modules are not supported.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:

    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    name: Build and Deploy Job

    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_LEMON_GLACIER_0C510BD03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match you app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          app_artifact_location: "public" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_LEMON_GLACIER_0C510BD03 }}
          action: "close"
```

I was trying to specify the Node version using this step:

```
- name: Setup Node 14.x
  uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: '14.x'
```

Still, the build process uses 12.8.

What am I doing wrong and is it possible to use a specific version in my case?

Comment: Please add the log to your question where it says that it's using 12.8. Per the documentation the action use Microsoft's build system Oryx, you'll probably have to configure this accordingly.

Comment: @riQQ I found docs and it says is supports only LTS version, which is 12.8. v14 will become LTS in october. I will close the question. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 11):

For those like me who came to this question well after 12.8 (and indeed 14.x) were considered "legacy" releases, and yet static-web-apps-deploy, even at v1, continues to use an old version of Node (in my case, 14.19.1), I found the answer on [a blog post by Edi Wang](https://edi.wang/post/2022/1/27/how-to-specify-nodejs-version-when-building-azure-static-web-app). It says to add an "engine" property to your package.json, with a "node" property specifying the version you need. Since I wanted v16 or above, I added the following:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
```

This caused Oryx to find and download Node v17.6.0:

```
Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  nodejs: 17.6.0
Version '17.6.0' of platform 'nodejs' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
```

Comment: I tried everything , but this comment saved me :D

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this is to add the following environment variable to your job in the github actions file:

```
 env:
  NODE_VERSION: 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that supported Node versions are only as high as LTS. 12.8 currently. You can't use the Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v0.0.1-preview action with v14.x right now.

I solved the problem by using github-actions and pushing the build to the azure storage.