# Error The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13 in Azure Pipelines

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-devops, angular-cli

My Azure pipeline started to fail. My error is at follows:

```json
Node.js version v16.20.2 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.
```

I didnt change anything. This is part of my pipeline:

```json
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build -c=release --output-path=web/wwwroot
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Two weeks ago that script works.

My question is, how to fix it in Azure pipelines? I am using Microsoft hosted agents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue with the same YAML Pipeline.

[image]

The cause of the issue is that the command: **npm install -g @angular/cli** will download the latest angular cli package by default.

The latest Angular CLI version 17.0.0 requests the node version 18.13.

To solve this issue, you can downgrade the angular CLI version in Azure Pipeline.

For example: `npm install -g @angular/cli@16.2.10`

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli@16.2.10
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: it worked, thank you

Comment: How to make it use the specific CLI version?

Comment: But I'm using Angular v17... so?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone here having this issue with Angular 17 and the AzureStaticWebApp@0 task, adding staticwebapp.config.json in the `src` directory with a 'platform' specification fixed it for me.

```
{
  ...
  "platform": {
    "apiRuntime": "node:18"
  }
  ...
}
```

ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#platform

Edit: I ran into the same issue on another repo and only got a successful build after ALSO adding in package.json

```
     "engines": {
        "node": ">=18.0.0"
      },
```

Comment: Is there anything else you need to do? I have tried in the src and the root directory, I have also tried adding it to angular.json assets section for both src and root directory. No matter what I do it still does the same thing with auto-detecting.

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  nodejs: 16.20.2
Version '16.20.2' of platform 'nodejs' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
Detected the following frameworks: Angular,Typescript

Comment: I ended up finding this post that fixed it for me. Adding an engines section to package.json defining a minimum node version.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73654739/2566689

Comment: Alternatively, I have tested using and environment variable which also worked as noted here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76873205/2566689. env: NODE_VERSION: 18

Comment: @kevindstanley thanks, I edited my response after encountering the issue on a second project, my issue was specific to azure repos