# Deploy angular app to static web app on azure

Tags: node.js, angular, yaml, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

i have a angular application that i want to be deployed on azure static web apps via git hub actions.
On my local machine:
angular cli 17
node 20
npm 10

> This is the yaml file.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          sub-modules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_VICTORIOUS_DESERT_030B8CE03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist/sun-club" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_VICTORIOUS_DESERT_030B8CE03 }}
          action: "close"
```

I am stuck with this error.

> Node.js version v16.20.2 detected.
> The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

I have tried to update the node version with a command from the yaml file but it seems that node 16 is default.

I tried to update the node version using nvm but no success.

Comment: for those who have this problem i found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810325/static-web-app-deploy-with-azure-using-specific-node-version?rq=2

Answer (score -1):

you can use the Github actions/setup-node action with a more recent version.

```html
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3  # Use v3 instead of v4
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          sub-modules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_VICTORIOUS_DESERT_030B8CE03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/"
          api_location: "api"
          output_location: "dist/sun-club"

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_VICTORIOUS_DESERT_030B8CE03 }}
          action: "close"
```

I changed actions/setup-node@v4 to actions/setup-node@v3 to use an older version of the action that supports Node.js 18.

let me know if this works.