# GitHub Actions fails when Angular CLI version is newer than required node version

Tags: angular, github-actions

I am trying to deploy my Angular project to an Azure static website.I developed the project using the latest Node version v21.5.0 and the version of my Angular CLI is 17.0.0.

Once done I created a static website in Azure and linked up my GitHub account with the right branch. This created a workflow file in GitHub Actions which I have specified below

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_NAME_HIDDEN_0CE9D2603 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_NAME_HIDDEN_0CE9D2603 }}
          action: "close"
```

How can I fix this?

In the Annotations I get the message

> Build and Deploy Job Failed to remove
> 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' from the git config

In the build & deploy step logs I get the error below.

> node.js version v16.20.2 detected. The Angular CLI requires a minimum
> Node.js version of v18.13.
>
> Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for
> additional instructions.

Attempting to install a later version of Node fails as it cannot seem to find the path to the `package.json`.

```
jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.13]
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install
```

I have rolled back the Angular CLI version to match one which is compatible with node version 16.20.2. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248452/is-there-a-compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js) was helpful to determine the compatibility.

Also this is my repo build configuration from the yml file

```
   ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "src" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "./" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

The build works now and the deployment succeeds but I think the angular is not compiling so it's all blank. Am I missing angular build directives

I found another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810325/static-web-app-deploy-with-azure-using-specific-node-version?rq=2) where someone had the same problem as myself

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question.

Comment: Can someone tell me the reason for the negative score please, @Azeem can you shed some light.

Comment: I believe only the voter may shed light on that.

Comment: Which step is that error coming from exactly?

Comment: Where did you call `@actions/setup-node` in your workflow? [cref](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-master.yml#L30)

Comment: @Pieterjan: The `ubuntu-latest` runner already has [NodeJS 18](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#installed-software) preinstalled and it's the [default](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/4d310f0a5908d895c80e2cd1ebb82c76f8693846/images/ubuntu/toolsets/toolset-2204.json#L293) too. So, that should not be an issue here.

Comment: @tribal: In your second update, the checkout step is missing.

Comment: @Azeem do you mean this - uses: actions/checkout@v3 before Setup node.js

Comment: @tribal: Yes, but I'm not sure how is that relevant here. You are using https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-deploy and it builds your source too. It's a docker action and internally uses a client which is [not open source](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/306) yet (issues tab is also disabled on its repo). Your issue seems to be related to that. You may try using [Azure Static Web Apps CLI](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli) instead, just to make sure that everything works without that action.

Comment: _"it cannot seem to find the path to the `package.json`"_ - which is... what? Is that in the root of the repo? Please give a [mre]. Where is the code even building; if it's just triggering a build _in Azure_ then the local Node etc. shouldn't matter at all.